# Is it possible to map logical OR value from database table's column into the list of objects using JPA/Hibernate (preferably JPA)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to map logical OR value from the database table's column into the list of objects using JPA/Hibernate (preferably JPA)?
Of course, there is another question - whether it makes sense do so, just now it is interesting to know whether it is possible to do that all?

The idea is the following:

- there is a column in the table, for example,

  ```
  product_types integer
  ```
- the value for product_types is the logical OR between available product types, where each product type is the enum value having numeric property: numeric value for product type i-th = 1 << (i-1), so 1-st product type numeric value is 1 (binary 0001), 2n-d is 2 (binary 0010), 3-rd is 4 (binary 0100), 4-th is 8 (binary 1000), etc.
- there are limited number of the available product types (no more than 10, does it matter at all?)

So, suppose we have the value for the product_types = 6 (0110), it means that product 2 and product 3 are used.

I would like to have the following entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Company {
...
    // add some JPA/Hibernate annotation here
    List<ProductType> productTypes;
...
}
```

Also, this should work for all search, update, insert, etc. queries.
Some kind of entity listener or pre/post processor?

P.S.: It is possible, and maybe it is better to do so using @ElementCollection and additional database table storing available products for the specific company. I am just curious is the described solution possible to implement?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there is some magic JPA annotation to do such processing.

Therefore, I would go with the `@PostLoad` and implement all the necessary operations there (i.e. creating the `List<ProductType>` attribute).

However, if you would need this `List<ProductType>` to be updateable, I guess you'd need an additional `@PrePersist` logic implemented as well.

Comment: Ok, assume you are right, these life-cycle annotations should help.
Thank you.